# Can HDMI or DisplayPort output to 1600x1200?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi, displayport

The Background:
I have 3 Samsung 204b monitors that I'm currently powering via NVidia 650 GTX (2 via DVI and one VGA).  The monitors support DVI-D (digital) and VGA signals.  I'm thinking of upgrading the video card (maybe to a 770 GTX or R9 280x), but one of the monitors will need to run from a DisplayPort or HDMI.

What I want to know is if a it's possible to use a DVI to HDMI (or DisplayPort) adapter and output to 1600x1200 which is the native resolution of my monitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes

HDMI and DVI are electrically [compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Compatibility_with_DVI)--that is, HDMI<->DVI adapters do nothing but map the digital video pins from one connector pinout directly to the other without any signal conversion.  (Note that HDMI does not have analog video pins and DVI does not support audio).

Although DisplayPort requires signal conversion, it is also able to output various resolutions.

Comment: Yup using a HDMI to DVI cable seems to work flawlessly.